# Option style glitch?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, select

I am working on a page that will let a logged in admin delete an employee.
After many try's and fail's, i finally did it. 
The page loops through a database table containing the employees login stuff(The password the employee set is not stored only a salt and hash mix) and finds all possible username of any employees. I created a test user and it looks like this: [i cant enter images so here is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3dmO.png). As you can see it is forced smaller and is tall for the one user it contains. If i delete the user all goes fine, but the select stays that way. The code for the form is as follows:

```
<form action="del_employee.php" method="POST">
    <select name="user[]" multiple>
         <?php foreach($rows as $row):?>
              <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
                  <?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
               </option>
          <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Delete Employee
    </button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this employee?
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" href="del_employee.php" value="Yes" class="btn btn-large btn-danger"></input>
                    <a href="del_employee.php" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">No</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Its just all bootstrap. Is this a known error? or does anyone know a work around is my question. (*Sorry for the horrible formatting on this i cant seem to do it right*)

Comment: I feel quite stupid but the problem was the `multiple` in the `<select>` element. My team added it and it came from there. Sorry for wasting anyone's time if i did.

Comment: Only thing I'd say for future is to properly display code with nice indentation. That block of code is highly unreadable and many won't bother.